# pg_restore is taking too long to finish. What could be the problem?

Tags: postgresql

pg_restore is taking too long to finish. I already performed the following

- `service postgresql initdb`
- `/etc/init.d/postgresql start`
- Modified `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` to use

  local   all         all                               trust

  host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident sameuser

  host    all         all         ::1/128               ident sameuser
- `/etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out out I was missing a parameter. What I was doing was

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d /path/to/backup/file/file.backup
```

instead of

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d databasename /path/to/backup/file/file.backup
```

I'm still not sure if the first one is not correct. I swear I could remember using that same syntax before.

Comment: The first one is incorrect. It will attempt to read a backup file from STDIN, not from your file.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, Magnus. Could you explain more about it?

Comment: The backup is sitting in the shell, waiting for input *from the shell*.  As such, it never starts, because no input is received.

Comment: Note, `databasename` is the name of an existing database in your postgres instance where restored dump will be placed